# Problemas ao instanciar objetos no python

Tags: python, classes, objetos, instanciar-objeto

Eu sou novo em programação, porém acabei de vir do Java e estou migrando para o Python.. Para começar criei uma simples classe Person com 3 atributos e tentei instanciar ela para ver a sintaxe, porém simplesmente não consigo entender porque não funciona...

A Classe

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, Name, Age, Height):
        self.name = Name
        self.age = Age
        self.height = Height
```

O arquivo "Main"

```
import Person

if __name__ == "__main__":
    person = Person("Mateus", 18, 1.8)
    print(person.name)
```

E dá o erro:

```
File "c:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\python\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    person = Person("Mateus", 18, 1.8)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Desculpa por ser burro e muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Vlw kkk sou novo aq tb

Comment: Como chama o arquivo que contém a classe? Ele é um módulo, e no topo do outro arquivo você precisa usar `from modulo import Person` em vez do que você fez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não conheço a estrutura de seu projeto, mas para poder ser possível invocar uma classe, você deve estar executando o seu código em uma python  path.

A definição de uma python-path é ter um arquivo `__init__.py` na sua estrutura de pastas de seu projeto python.

Segue um exemplo da estrutura de pastas:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── person.py
└── main.py
```

Segue como é o conteúdo dos arquivos:

***person.py***

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, Name, Age, Height):
        self.name = Name
        self.age = Age
        self.height = Height
```

***main.py***

```
from person import Person

if __name__ == "__main__":
    person = Person("Mateus", 18, 1.8)
    print(person.name)
```

depois para invocar esta função basta executar o seguinte comando:

```
python main.py
#Mateus
```

Após executar este comando o seu código será executado com sucesso.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Agradeço mt